# How to set silverlight comboboxitem value in xaml

Tags: silverlight, combobox

I create a datatemplate for a combobox as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AircraftTypeTemplate">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="340">
           <ComboBox>
               <ComboBoxItem>CJ1</ComboBoxItem>
               <ComboBoxItem>CJ3</ComboBoxItem>
               <ComboBoxItem>Bravo</ComboBoxItem>
               <ComboBoxItem>Excel</ComboBoxItem>
               <ComboBoxItem>Sovereign</ComboBoxItem>
           </ComboBox>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

It renders fine, but I would like to be able to associate a value with each of the items without having to bind it to some data context. For example I would like the CJ1 comboboxitem to have a value of 5. How would I set those in XAML?

Like:

```
<ComboBoxItem Value="5">CJ1</ComboBoxItem>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the `Name` property to be any arbitrary string and use that.  For more flexibility, you can use the `Tag` property, which according to MSDN:

> > Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this object.

You can read more about `Tag` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.95).aspx).  I'd say `Tag` is probably better as opposed to bending `Name` to your will, and you can stick a string into `Tag` just as easily as `Name`.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing: how would I bind the SelectedValue of the combobox to the tag?

Comment: No problem.  To bind the `SelectedValue` to `Tag` would look like `<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" />`.